# 'Run code' is not working in Visual Studio Code (Ubuntu c language)

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

i'm trying to run C Program to find sum of two numbers.

When I click 'Run code' on the top right corner, or right click then click 'Run code', or use Ctrl+Alt+N, the integrated terminal does not appear and code could not run.

PS: when i run hello world code it works but when i use scanf() or gets() i get this problem.

i use ubuntu 20.04,so what is the solution?
[image]

[image]

Comment: probably your program runs but you do not see the message. Move the `\n` at the end of your string rather than at the beginning, to flush the output, and you will see the message asking to input the values

Comment: @bruno yes i tried to move the \n to the end but nothing happens

Comment: do the commands by hand in a terminal. I always do by hand, to use IDE to execute a code is often a source of problem ( I do not speak about a debugger like *gdb* of course ). You can cut in 3 commands (one per line) rather than in one with the `&&`

Comment: @bruno i solved it lol, i had to go to the menu Code > Preferences > Settings then find Extensions and check the box Run in Terminal.